# Submit a form in Folium HTML Popup

Tags: python, popup, html, folium, flask

In my flask application I have a folium map displayed inside an iframe. I defined a folium html popup with a form.  How can I route the form?

Here is my popup html code:

```
"""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
    <table style="height: 100px; width: 250px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 200px;background-color: white; align:center;"><strong>{}</strong></td>""".format(row['properties.NTAName']) + """</tr>
            <tr>
            <tr><td style="align:center;">
                <form id="restForm" method='POST' action='/exp_neigh' style="border: 1px solid #333333;padding:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                    <input type="hidden" id="lat_boc" name="latitude" value="{}" """ .format(lat) + """> 
                    <input type="hidden" id="lon_box" name="longitude" value="{}" """ .format(lon) + """>
                    <button type="submit" class="button">Select this neighbourhood</button>
                </form>
            <tr><td>
        </tbody></table>
            </html>"""
```

Here is my Flask route:

```
@app.route('/exp_neigh', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def exp_neigh():

    return render_template('neighbour.html')
```

[image: Here is Map with the pop]